# Model binding in Razor View (ASP.NET MVC3) at runtime

Tags: data-binding, razor

My Index method renders a Strongly Typed View of type (`InitDetails`), auto generated code looks like the following:

```
@ModelType BookingDeamon.InitDetails

@Using Html.BeginForm()
@Html.ValidationSummary(True)
@<fieldset>
    <legend>Reservation</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Pickup)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Pickup)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Pickup)
        </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="SubmitMe()" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
End Using
```

On the above form, I want to display a select list box, as i'll be controlling this select list via JQuery to load different contents depending on different things.

I want to be able to deliver the value of that select list box as Pickup value.

when I try to do the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.Pickup)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DropDownListFor' accepts this number of argument
```

Is it possible when user clicks on the submit button, instead of taking Pickup (textbox) value to the controller; it takes the value from the dropdownlist box and submit it to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(ModelType=>Model.Pickup, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Pickup"],"--Select--")
```

in your controller

```
var Pickup= GetPickupList();
var PickupList= new SelectList(Pickup, "value", "Text", Pickup.DefaultSelectedValueIfAnyNeeded);
ViewData["Pickup"] = PickupList
```

write a function GetPickupList()
that returns a list of Pickup values.